# Create drop-down list based on two other criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, dropdownlist

I have a range of data relating to buildings. The fields are building type, entry into the building, and size of the building.

I have created drop-down lists for the building and entry type. I now want to create a drop-down list for the size of building but only the sizes that apply to the selected building type and entry (linked somehow to the building type and entry drop-down). See the image for the range of data I am wanting to use as well the drop down cells I plan to use to do the selection.

[image]

Ultimately, once the user has selected the type, entry and size, the resultant cost of that building will show which I plan to achieve by using `xlookup` with multiple criteria.

How can I can create the dynamic drop-down list based off of the building type and entry?

I am using Excel 365 Pro Plus.

Answer (score -1):

*This needs few array formula to filter records and then connect them with Drop Down.*

- **Note:**
- For better understanding I've used only few records from each category.
- Shown method works with all versions of Excel, including 365.

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- An Array (CSE) formula in cell E2, creates unique list of Building Type.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$20),0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** *Create Drop Down in cell E13 and use E2:E3 as List value.*

---

- An array (CSE) formula in G2, gets relates Entry Type value.

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$20, MATCH(0, IF($E$13=$A$2:$A$20, COUNTIF($G$1:$G1, $B$2:$B$20), ""), 0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** *Create Drop Down in cell G13 and use G2:G3 as List value.*

---

- Cell H2 has an array (CSE) formula, gets related Overall Size.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$20, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$13, $A$2:$A$20)*COUNTIF($G$13, $B$2:$B$20), ROW($A$2:$C$20)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$20))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** *Create Drop Down in cell H13 and use H2:H10 as List value.*

---

- *Finish array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*
- *You may adjust cell references in formula and Drop Down List value as needed.*
- Formula returns Entry Type & Overall Size, depends on the data, at source in range A2:C20.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, this was very helpful. I have two follow on questions. First, it seems the formula in H2 is dependant on the table layout shown. if the data starts a couple rows down or columns across (i.e A1 is actually in B2) the formula doesnt work. How would I amend the formula - does it have to do with the +1? Secondly, again for the formula in H2 - how would I add sorting and removing duplicates? Example - column C is made up of LxBxH = volume. I have another column with just LxB (area) but there are to heights. When I create the formula on area, it shows duplicates. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Grant,,, it's simple you need to adjust CELL REFERENCES in the formula if & when data at SOURCE changes,,, like for formula in E2 has source A2:A20,,, suppose BUILDING TYPE data are in B2:B20 or elsewhere, you need to replace A2:A20 with NEW RANGE,, and so for others. Formula in H2 reads OVER ALL SIZE according to Drop Down values in E13 & G13,,, and you have duplicate Overall size at source in C2:C20 for different categories,,, if U remove duplicates, which is possible,, then technically it's wrong,, since Building & Entry Type has few common Overall size.

Comment: **Continue,,** now if U find that my post is useful to you please accept it as an Answer as  well Up vote also,, [Check the link](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺